# How to fix count that doesn't work in while loop

Tags: bash, shell

I have been trying to resolve an issue where my loop's count should decrease, however nothing is working. I need to create a while loop that will read over a given amount of times. For instance, if I enter in "files.txt -a 3" in the terminal, I need my loop to repeat "Enter in a string: " 3 times. With my code below, I am only able to get it to loop once. I am not to sure where to put the counter and I can say that I have put it everywhere. Inside the if statement, in inside of the for loop, and inside the while loop but none seem to work. The number that the user will put is held in the $count variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
if ["$1" = "-a" ]
then
  read in user String and save into file
fi

while [ "$count" > 0 ]
do
  for i in $count
  do

   if [ "-a" ]
   then
   read -p "Enter in a string: " userSTR
   echo userSTR >> files.txt
   count=$(($count - 1))
   fi

done
done
```

Comment: Where do you initialise `$count`? `for i in $count` does nothing useful.

Comment: I get it from: 
loop=1 
if [ "$1" = "-n" ] 
then
     count=$2
fi
I must have forgot that part sorry. If I enter in "files.txt -a 3" then the three will be saved into the $count variable. For the for loop I am not to sure what to put to loop through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For conditional expression you need to use `[[ expression ]]`, e.g. this will loop four times:

```
count=4
while [[ $count > 0 ]] ; do
    echo "$count"
    count=$(( $count - 1 ))
done
```

To fetch the count from the command-line argument, you could replace the assignment `count=4` above with the following, parsing the command-line arguments:

```
if [ $# -lt 2 ] ; then
    echo "Usage: $0 -a [count]"
    exit 1
fi
if [ "$1" = "-a" ] ; then
    shift
    count=$1
fi
```

Comment: Hi! How could I switch out the count number (for you, you put 4) so that it will respond to what the user puts in the terminal. Say I wrote "files.txt -a 3." I want the three to be put in the count variable. It will change every time. I'm very new to writing in bash so in a way I am looking to store the number the user gives (or would it be the argument the user gives) if that that sense...

Comment: I updated the example to include how to fetch the count from a command-line argument.

Comment: Thank you so much!! My answer came out a lot different but I was able to figure it out through your example :D